# Can I restrict an owner of a group to only add members but not new owners?

Tags: azure, admin, rbac, azure-rbac

Is there a way to restrict owner of groups from adding new owners?
Would like them to only have the ability to add/remove members.

We have restricted regular users from using our admin portals, so the owners are using https://myaccount.microsoft.com/groups to manage the groups.

I can't find any information about editing the Owner-role for groups.

Comment: You might want to check access packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create That (and access review) might be a thing you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I restrict an owner of a group to only add members but not new owners?

You can create an Custom Role for a Groups Administrator that does not allow assigning owner to the groups.

Follow the below steps to create an custom role.

1. Go to  **Azure Active Directory**  >  **Roles and administrators**  >  **New custom role**.

[image]

2. Select the required permission to manage the group as below.

[image]

3. After creating the custom role, assign the same role to the user for managing groups.
4. Once assign the role the user is unable to add owner to the groups and he can add members to the group.

[image]

Reference:  [Manage Azure Active Directory groups and group membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups)

Comment: Hi, the pictures you pasted are not available. Could you fix them so I can check out your solution?

Comment: Pictures are available, kindly check with different network if any blockages on current network (Mobile).